# (1052, "Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous")

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I get the bellow error when I query my instances:

> (1052, "Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous")

If I use:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/physicalserver/list/?switchesport__id=5
```

I can get the right results.

but if I use:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/physicalserver/list/?switchesport__bandwidth=10
```

I will get the error.

My list API view is bellow:

```
class PhysicalServerListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PhysicalServerListSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    filters = {'{}__contains'.format(key): value
                   for key, value in query_params.items()}

    return PhysicalServer.objects.filter(**filters)
```

How can I use the `switchesport__bandwidth` as the query param?

Comment: This is most likely an SQL issue, can you post the actual query being ran?

Comment: whats the meaning of ` the actual query being ran`?